# IntelliJ - compile all CoffeeScript files at once

Tags: intellij-idea, coffeescript

I use a [CoffeeScript file watcher in IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/transpiling-coffeescript-to-javascript.html) to compile my CoffeeScript files. However, when I start the IDE, it does not interpret the files immediately. In the project structure, there are two files visible:

[image: two files js and coffee visible]

When I open the coffee file and change something, then the watcher is launched and compiles my script, which is also visible in the project structure:

[image: compiled coffee]

Is there a way to tell IntelliJ that it should "precompile" all .coffee scripts in a project?

The problem is not only about the visibility of both .js and .coffee files. I want to store only .coffee files in the repository so initial compilation will be mandatory after the checkout.

I know I might use Grunt or even a coffee watcher to compile them, but my project involves a few really *non-consoleable* folks.